# show all foreign keys - SQL Anywhere

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, sybase, sqlanywhere

Can anyone tell me how to list all the foreign keys in a SQL Anywhere database ?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the SYS.SYSFOREIGNKEYS system table. It lists the primary table, foreign table, foreign key name, and the column(s) involved.

*Disclosure: I work for SAP in SQL Anywhere engineering.*